# What does the word full-size mean?

Tags: meaning

I understand that full-size means "it's full sized", but I am not sure relative to what?

> This is a full-size pistol.

Does "full-size" mean something is within the normal size range within a gun class when used for guns? For example, a shotgun that's the size of a full-size pistol would be called a compact shotgun. Is this the case or not? I am asking, because looking up a dictionary doesn't really help to get the meaning right.

Answer (score 1):

We use 'full-size' to say that something is a normal size **for its type**, and often included in the meaning is that smaller-size versions are possible. A full-size pistol is distinguished from a small or miniature pistol. A shotgun the same size as a full-size pistol would be a very small shotgun.

> full-size 
>   adjective (also full-sized)
>   of the normal size, not of a reduced size:
>
> *The company's latest mini-netbook comes with a
>   full-size keyboard.*

[Full-size (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/full-size)